# Can you print tables on a popup window or on a screen in kivy (python)

Tags: python, kivy, tabular

I have a program that scrapes information from a webpage and stores it in a list, then prints this using `tabulate.tabulate`. I am now trying to turn this program into a more usable GUI using kivy. However, the tutorials I have seen only show how to write on a Screen or Pop-up using `Label`, which only seems to print text, not tables. So I don't think I can print a table there (at least not using tabulate).

So my question is, is what I am trying to do possible, and if so, how?

Edit: What I have tried

.kv file

```py
WindowManager:
    Screen1:

<Screen1>
    name: 'screen1'

    Label:
        text: tabulate([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]])
```

.py file

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from tabulate import tabulate

kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: Your information about `Popup` is wrong. You can put anything in a `Screen` or `Popup`

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sorry I didn't write that part very clearly. I meant to say: the tutorials I have seen only show how to write on a Screen or Pop-up using label, which only seems to print text, not tables. I haven't seen how to add any other things to Screen or Popup

Comment: Doesn't `tabulate` just print text?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I edited my question to show what I tried. I have imported tabulate in the python file, but I get an error message which says `NameError: name 'tabulate' is not defined`.

Comment: At the start of your `kv` file, add the line `#:import tabulate tabulate.tabulate`.

Comment: And you will likely want to use a mono-space font to get the tables to look OK.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Great, that seems to work well, thanks so much! I have two further questions. (You can answer it in the answers so I can accept your answer): 1) How can I change the font to this mono-space font? And 2) I currently have it written in such a way that the table I want to print must be written in kivy, but when I want to use the program, the tabular data will be coming from the logic in the code. How can I get a variable from the python file to be printed in the kivy Label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Label` using `ids` that are set in the `kv` file. Also, if you access `tabulate` outside of the `kv` file, you no longer need that `import` inside the `kv` file. Here is a modified `kv` file that adds an `id` for the `Label` (and also adds a `Button` to trigger the table build):

```
WindowManager:
    Screen1:

<Screen1>
    name: 'screen1'

    Label:
        id: table    # this is the id
        font_name: 'DejaVuSansMono'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.9}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size

    Button:
        text: 'Make Table'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0.1}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        on_release: root.make_table()
```

The above code also assigns a mono-spaced font to the `Label`. I can't guarantee that your system will have that specific font. And then in your `Screen1` class, define the `make_table()` method:

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    def make_table(self):
        self.ids.table.text = tabulate([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]])
```